# cybin.ProtocolError: No protocol version header

Tags: python, thrift-protocol

I installed python 2.7 and tried to use happybase to communicate with hbase thrift server.

python2.7 test.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    for key, data in table.rows([b'row01']):
  File "/home/qa/happybase/happybase/table.py", line 162, in rows
    self.name, rows, columns, {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thriftpy-0.3.8-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 160, in _req
    return self._recv(_api)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thriftpy-0.3.8-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 172, in _recv
    fname, mtype, rseqid = self._iprot.read_message_begin()
  File "thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.pyx", line 439, in cybin.TCyBinaryProtocol.read_message_begin (thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.c:6457)
cybin.ProtocolError: No protocol version header
```

There is no cybin.c under /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thriftpy-0.3.8-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg

Cloned https://github.com/eleme/thriftpy.git

cybin.c isn't there either.

Advice on how to get over the error is appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43705922/499466